# Probability of events where outcomes do not have equal probability

Tags: probability

so I'm taking an intro to probability course and this question was given as part of the first assignment. I've read over notes and course material but nothing seems to be relevant to question such as this (i.e. all outcomes a1, a2, etc. not having equal probability). I've guessed that I need to incorporate partitions in some way, but honestly I'm at a loss.

I was wondering if somebody could point me in the right direction. Given this is for an assignment, I'm not looking for a solution, just a little bit of advice. The question is as follows:

Let the sample space Ω = {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6} be given. Assume that: Let A = {a1, a2, a3}, B = {a2, a4}, C =
{a4, a5, a6}, D = {a2} and E = {a4}. If P(A) = P(B) = P(C) and P(D) = 2P(E). Find:

(a) P(A ∩ D')

(b) P(A ∪ E)

(c) P(A|B')

Thanks in advance!

Comment: notice that the sets $A$ and $C$ are mutually exclusive and exhaustive in $\Omega$  so $P(A) + P(C)=1$

Comment: Thanks! Though to clarify, I'm still lost as to how I should be expressing the probability. Do I have to figure out the likelyhood of each outcome, or express it in terms of other events? Or am I completely off-base?

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out. As P(A) + P(C) = 1, then P(A) = P(B) = P(C) = 1/2. And then I could deduce from there. Thanks for the tip!!

Answer (score 1):

> Let the sample space $Ω = \{a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5, a_6\}$ be given. Assume that: Let $A = \{a_1, a_2, a3\}, B =\{a_2, a_4\}, C = \{a_4, a_5, a_6\}, D = \{a_2\}$ and $E = \{a_4\}$. If $P(A) = P(B) = P(C)$ and $P(D) = 2P(E)$.

$$\begin{array}{|l|l:6l|}\hline & a_1 & a_2 & a_3 & a_4 & a_5 & a_6 \\ \hline A & \checkmark & 2x & \checkmark  \\ \hdashline B && 2x  && x \\ \hdashline C &&&& x & \checkmark & \checkmark \\ \hdashline D && 2x \\ \hdashline E &&&& x \\ \hline \end{array}$$

$P(E)=x, P(D) = 2x, P(A) = P(B) = P(C) =3x$

Also $P(A)+P(C)=1$ so...

Answer (score 0):

Work it out where the probability of a1, a2... a6 is equal. For a, that's the probability for a1 or a3 but not a2, which is P(a1, a3), which is 1/3. For b, which is for A or E, which is P(a1, a2, a3, a4), which is 2/3. I expect you can work out the third one. (If you can't, ask me.)

Comment: But how can they be equal if P(a2) = 2P(a4)? Am I overthinking it?

Comment: Let $P(a_4)=x, P(a_2)=2x$ then $P(a_2\cup a_4)=3x~=P(B)$ and...